# How to i total all results up by days

Tags: group-by

I'm trying to total the results by days of the week. For example, the hospital should show how many patients the had on Monday's for the month. 
I have this as far as the query

```
 Select Datename(weekday,AdmitDate) as Weekday,h.[Hospital Name],
           Count(*) as Admits

  from Visits as V
  Join Hospitals as H 
  ON h.HospitalID= v. HospitalID
  Group by [Hospital Name],AdmitDate
```

Thank you for looking and helping./

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should group by `Datename(weekday,AdmitDate)` instead of `AdmitDate`.

Some dbs (e.g. mysql) lets you project something you do not group by, but this is not correct and may gives incorrect results.

Everything you project in the select clause and is not in an aggregation function must be grouped by.

Comment: would you know how to sort by days of the week in order from sunday to friday?

Comment: it dependps on the type of database you are using. dbs have slightly different implementations of sql. some implementation of sql let you set the "first day of the week", so, then you can order by, starting from the day you want.